# How detailed are employers in background checks?

Tags: job-offer, human-resources, background-check, employer

I understand that employers will check employment and academic history including the dates.

But does anyone know if they will check the specific projects/tasks that you mention in your resume?

Is it a common industry practice to do so?

Comment: How are supposed to know how your manager will react? Voting to close because giving you the answer to the question you are asking would require us to be aware of the company's policy regarding reference inquires, how tightly they enforce those policies, and what your manager decides to say. Nobody on this site has a crystal ball.

Comment: 9 out of 10 questions on this site are also open-ended like this. Most of them depends on the employer to answer but people still have general answers. You might as well close 90% of the questions here.

Comment: Why do you care if they ask about what you did?

Comment: Depends on what sort of clearance the employer is doing formal security clearance goes a lot deeper than a basic check at Jow Shmoes Auto traders. to vague vote to close

Comment: I've got to agree that the general answer is "it varies". I doubt they check everyone, but they *may* do spot-checks when they're down to the few individuals they're actually interested in hiring. You'd better assume that, in any case. Some spin is accepted in a resume, since it's understood that everyone tries to present themselves in the best light possible... but anything that crosses the line into being a lie will get you rejected "with prejudice."

Answer (score 3):

This depends wildly on country and industry.  Some will check on such details by default, others won't.

If they suspect something on the resume is a lie, they may make the effort to verify it.  Or they may just throw the resume in the trash and decide it's not worth the risk.

Either way, as long as you don't lie on your resume, whether or not they call someone and verify it should be a non-issue.